# How to call another method after processOrder completed in chatbot using FormFlow?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bots, chatbot, botframework

I'm using FormFlow. When a bot finishes with all the questions and calls `processOrder`, I want to continue with the dialog, but I don't know where I should call another method:

```
 OnCompletionAsyncDelegate<Form> processOrder = async (context, state) =>
        {
            await context.PostAsync("You done");
              // context.Call(OnFormComplete);
        };
```

When I try to call like this, I get this message:

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'resume' of 'IDialogStack.Call(IDialog, ResumeAfter)' Project1    C:\Projects\Good Version\v-17.2.2017\demo-Project1\Project1\Dialogs\Form.cs 34  Compiler    IntelliSense    Active  Compiler

I call the form flow in this mode in my rootdialog.cs:

```
 var myform = new FormDialog<Form>(new Form(), Form.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart, null);

                context.Call(myform, ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
```

Formbuilder is:

```
return new FormBuilder<Form>()
            .Field(nameof(Time))
            .Field(nameof(Number1))
            .Field(nameof(Number2))
            .AddRemainingFields()

             .Confirm("Would you like to process")
              .OnCompletion(processOrder)
            .Build();
```

I want to continue the dialog because the bot stopped. How can I call another method and where should I call?

Comment: after formflow build how can i call another dialog

Answer (score 0):

You would to something like this in you formFlow class:

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomFormDialog
{
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public int Number1 { get; set; }
    public int Number2 { get; set; }

    public static IForm<CustomFormDialog> Build()
    {
        OnCompletionAsyncDelegate<CustomFormDialog> processOrder = async (context, state) =>
        {
            await context.Forward(new OtherFormDialog(state), onOtherFormProcessed, state, CancellationToken.None);
        };

        return new FormBuilder<CustomFormDialog>()
            .Field(nameof(Time))
            .Field(nameof(Number1))
            .Field(nameof(Number2))
            .AddRemainingFields()

            .Confirm("Would you like to process?")
            .OnCompletion(processOrder)
            .Build();
    }

    private static async Task onOtherFormProcessed(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<CustomFormDialog> result)
    {
        var formValue = await result;

        await context.PostAsync($"You are again in the form: Time: {formValue.Time}, Number1: {formValue.Number1}, Number2: {formValue.Number2}");
    }
}
```

I defined a dummy dialog that receives the response of the formFlow dialog, and do some stuff and call the done for that dialog and came back to the FormFlow class:

```
public class OtherFormDialog : IDialog<CustomFormDialog>
{
    private readonly CustomFormDialog formData;

    public OtherFormDialog(CustomFormDialog prevState)
    {
        this.formData = prevState;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        //Here, we can do anything
        await context.PostAsync("I'll check your data. Please wait!");

        await context.PostAsync("Just joking! No validation at all.");
        context.Done(this.formData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer...i appreciate so much .  I want to ask something else that i can't do it ... I want to call my rootDialog after the user confirm the formflow...please can you advice me how to call ...where to call it ?